# Unmanaged ethernet switch buffer behaviour

Tags: ethernet, switch, buffer

If I have a typical unmanaged switch connected to a server at 1Gps and several clients at 100Mbps, will the switch buffer the packets?

For example, if two clients are downloading files, can the server send a packet for a second client before the first packet has finished going down the line?

Comment: This information is commonly available on the internet and explained in more depth and detail than what we should need to do here. Switches do buffer traffic for multiple reasons. The full duplex nature of TCP means the sender will wait for the receiver to respond causing the connection between the two to run at the slower speed. If your questions is “Can multiple 100Mbps connections share the speed of the single 1Gbps server?” Then yes, they can. Theoretically, 10 computers could transfer a file at full speed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a typical unmanaged switch connected to a server at 1Gps and several clients at 100Mbps, will the switch buffer the packets?

The switch buffers a certain amount of frames, depending on the model.

> if two clients are downloading files, can the server send a packet for a second client before the first packet has finished going down the line?

"Down the line" is ambiguous. As soon as the server has finished transmitting the packet for the first client (which is buffered by the switch and subsequently forwarded at the client's lower rate) it can transmit the packet for the second client.

Basically, a server connected with 1 Gbit/s can feed 10 clients connected with 100 Mbit/s at their full speed - assuming it can provide the data fast enough and only the network is limiting the speed.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things an Ethernet switch can do:

*Store and forward* - wait until entire frame is received before sending it.

*Cut through* - start sending frame as soon as destination address is known.

The destination MAC address is the very first thing in an Ethernet frame so there's not very much buffered before a cut through switch will start sending what it gets - some hubs had a "Fragment Free" feature which waits 64 bytes before sending in order to avoid bothering the destination if a collision would occur.

> can the server send a packet for a second client before the first packet has finished going down the line

Communication between, for example, your PC and the switch it is immediately connected to, can only handle 1 bit at a time, and the network hardware is modulating the medium over a period of time to "send" the data.  Any serial communications protocol works like this.

So a NIC can never send more than one frame "at once" - they are queued up (Quality-of-Service affects this queueing order) and processed by the server's network stack and hardware working together. (NIC teaming/bonding can make multiple NICs work together like one NIC.)

If you transmit something to the Internet, there are almost always multiple "hops" - server sends data to your switch, which forwards to your router, which forwards to possibly more routers, then your ISPs router, then your ISPs upstream IXP, etc., etc.  Your server's NIC doesn't have to wait for all these hops to complete, of course, it can work on sending another frame to the switch as soon as the NIC is done with the current frame.

Definitely multiple packets can be in flight among all these "hops" - and there's a chance they may or may not arrive in order on the other end - this is something TCP addresses with sequence numbers and windows (UDP does not).  Cut through/store and forward only affects the immediate connection between the server and switch, though.

Need to check the specs of your switch to know what it does.  [This one](http://www.tendacn.com/en/product/specification/TEG1008D.html), for example, does "store and forward."

Comment: Well, I'm actually looking to decide which switch! You see I have heard it said that cheap unmanaged switches don't have sufficient buffer space store a packet (1508 bytes) for each port. Store and forward implies that the packet is completely buffered before being sent out on another port, but does that specifically imply that it will be able to receive another packet on the incoming port as soon as it has 'transferred' the packet to the buffer of the destination port? Or should I be looking for an additional spec to ensure this?